# Python and Zope: Module will import in python but not in zope

Tags: python, zope

I have installed the Image module http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/. I then try and import it in the python interpreter and successfully so:

```
>>> import Image
>>>
```

But when I try to import the module in Zope via DTML page:

DTML page looks like:

```
<dtml-var import_image>
```

Which calls this script:

```
def import_image(self):
    import Image
    im = Image.open("/home/rv/Desktop/blah.jpg")
    return im
```

I then get this error:

"ImportError: No module named Image" How can there be no module when I can import it in the python interpreter?

---

EDIT

The python script is in Zopes extension folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import PIL.Image
```

rather than:

```
import Image
```

Zope has an Image module and you could be encountering a namespace clash.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t just import any module in zope python script. Zope has some security restrictions. In your case you need create external method in %zope-instance%/Extensions

**OR** maybe your zope instance cannot find this library because it's running in another python environment. You should check if all parameters are right in %zope-instance%/bin/zopectl

Comment: the file is in my extensions folder